# Twilio Transcription Callback

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, callback, twilio, ibm-watson

I'm trying to create a Twilio app, that can make outgoing calls, get them transcribed by Voicebase, then send them back as a JSON callback and be stored in a pyMongo database. However, when I use ngrok to test it out, nothing gets printed to the console to show that it's working. I've provided my code for app.py below:

```
import os
import re
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response
from faker import Factory
from twilio.jwt.client import ClientCapabilityToken
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Dial
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Record, VoiceResponse
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Dial, Number, VoiceResponse
from twilio import twiml
import json
import os
import requests, time
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)
fake = Factory.create()
alphanumeric_only = re.compile('[\W_]+')
phone_pattern = re.compile(r"^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/token', methods=['GET'])
def token():
    # get credentials for environment variables
    account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
    auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    application_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID']
    # Generate a random user name
    identity = alphanumeric_only.sub('', fake.user_name())

    # Create a Capability Token
    capability = ClientCapabilityToken(account_sid, auth_token)
    capability.allow_client_outgoing(application_sid)
    capability.allow_client_incoming(identity)
    token = capability.to_jwt()

    # Return token info as JSON
    return jsonify(identity=identity, token=token.decode('utf-8'))


@app.route("/voice", methods=['POST'])
def voice():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    add_ons = json.loads(request.values['AddOns'])
    if "To" in request.form and request.form["To"] != '':
        dial = Dial(
            caller_id=os.environ['TWILIO_CALLER_ID'],
            record='record-from-answer-dual',
            recording_status_callback=['website_url']
        )
        # wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
        # by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
        if phone_pattern.match(request.form["To"]):
            dial.number(request.form["To"])
        else:
            dial.client(request.form["To"])
        resp.append(dial)
    else:
        resp.say("Thanks for calling!")

    return Response(str(resp), mimetype='text/xml')

@app.route("/callback", methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
def callback():
    print('activated')
    add_ons = json.loads(request.values['AddOns'])

    # If the Watson Speech to Text add-on found nothing, return immediately
    payload_url = add_ons["results"]["voicebase_transcription"]["payload"][0]["url"]

    account_sid = os.environ.get('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
    auth_token = os.environ.get('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
    resp = requests.get(payload_url, auth=(account_sid, auth_token)).json()
    print('working')
    results = resp['results'][0]['results']
    transcripts = map(lambda res: res['alternatives'][0]['transcript'], results)
    print(transcripts)
    client = MongoClient()
    posts = db.posts
    post_data = {
        'results': results,
        'content': transcripts
    }
    result = posts.insert_one(post_data)
    print('One post: {0}'.format(result.inserted_id))
    return ''.join(transcripts)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I assume that in your `/voice` route you are just blanking out the URL in this line? `recording_status_callback=['website_url']` It looks as though it should just be `/callback` though (you can use relative URLs). When you say nothing gets printed to the console, you mean that the call works correctly, but `/callback` is not being called?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I'm just putting ['website_url'] in its place, I normally use an ngrok url to test it. The call, and recording the call, both work fine. But nothing gets printed in the callback side.

Comment: When you say recording the call works, how do you know? Can you see the [call log in you console](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls)? Does that show it trying to hit the callback url?

Comment: The calls get recorded in the Twilio console, and I'm able to access them from there.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here. You are using ngrok to tunnel the webhooks to your application. Are you sure you have the right ngrok URL selected, they change every time? Do you see a request in the ngrok dashboard?

Comment: Thanks, I finally got the callback to work. It now, however, returns a keyError for 'Results', particularly the line: results = resp['results'][0]['results']

Comment: I would probably inspect the object that you are returned and find out what sort of data shape you expect there. I don't know the structure of it off the top of my head, but you have it in front of you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, what is an 'object shape', and how do I check for it? Most of what's printed to the console is several lines similar to this:   File "/Users/name/DojoPython/myEnv/py2FlaskEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request"

Comment: I mean you should `print` the `resp` dictionary after you load it. That way you will be able to see what it all looks like and whether you actually have `resp['results'][0]['results']` or whether you need to change that.

Comment: I'm also getting a '500 Internal Service Error' on the callback for the Ngrok terminal.

Comment: That's because your app is throwing an error, you need to get that data out of the response correctly.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I've printed resp, and all the information comes in just fine when I do that. It seems to be a problem with indexing resp under ['results'][0]['results']

Comment: Perhaps you could share an example of `resp` (update your question, rather than in the comments) and I’ll take a look at it and see what might be wrong.